# Inside AJAX function the variable has a valid value, outside not

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I tried to use global variable and use return clause, but the variable remains null when left the AJAX function.

```
   http.onreadystatechange =  
     function() { if(http.readyState==4 && http.status==200) {
                        vQuantity = http.responseText;
                        alert(vQuantity);
                }
     }
```

The alert message (above) showed me a valid value and the variable is global, but returning of the AJAX function the value is null. Do you all have any ideas?
Thanks buddies, Marcos.

The AJAX routine was ok, but I'd like to use a variable that was loaded (at least should to be) outside AJAX routine and the variable is null.

How can I do this? Below you all can see my code:

```
    <form><input type=hidden name="ElementoQuantidade"></form>

    function updateinsertAJAX(CodPagina) {
       var http;
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          http=new XMLHttpRequest();
       } 
       else 
       {
        http=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }

       var urlalvo = "updateinsertSQL.php";
       var compl = "?codpagina=" + CodPagina + "&t=";
       var randomize = parseInt(Math.random()*999999999999999);
       var modurl = urlalvo + compl + randomize;

       http.open("GET", modurl, true);

       http.onreadystatechange =  
         function() { if(http.readyState==4 && http.status==200) {
           var vqtde = http.responseText;
           document.getElementById('ElementoQuantidade').innerHTML = vqtde;
           }
           else
           {
            document.getElementById('ElementoQuantidade').innerHTML = "a lot of";
           }
       }
      http.send();
    }
```

Actually, I'd like to use that variable vqtde, but when I use it outside AJAX function, that variable (vqtde) is null. Inside AJAX function the variable (vqtde) has a valid value.

Could you please guide me? Thanks a lot and have a pleasant day.
Marcos

Comment: I got it. I did the following: 1) I executed the Debugger of I.E.9 to understand a little better, 2) I changed from true (asynchronous) to false (synchronous). Now, I don't have AJAX, but SJAX. I'll verify this new situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var vqtde; // make it global 


function updateinsertAJAX(CodPagina) {
       var http;
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { ........
```

**AND**

```
http.onreadystatechange =  
         function() { if(http.readyState==4 && http.status==200) {
           vqtde = http.responseText; ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you return the value from your function? I would advise against global variables unless they're necessary, just because they can get lost in the shuffle if your application grows.

```
function yourFn(...) {
   ...do some stuff...
   return yourVariable;
}
```